# open62541: get all changed monitored items of subscription at the same time

Tags: c++, opc-ua, open62541

As far as I can see from the OPC-UA specifications, on every publishing interval OPC-UA server sends one NotificationMessage containing all Notifications of all changes (I'm monitoring variable values) it has sampled in queue.

But as I found in open62541 documentation, its subscription methods `UA_Client_MonitoredItems_createDataChange` and `UA_Client_MonitoredItems_createDataChanges` work on "callback per every single monitored item" basis. Item by item.

Is there a way to get all the monitored items changes of one publishing interval in bulk?

1-st publishing interval: changed values of items 1, 2, 3

2-nd publishing interval: changed values of items 2, 4, 5

etc...

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, this depends on the software stack you are using. (E.g. Softing, Microsoft .NET Standard). A NotificationMessage contains all changes of a MonitoredItem which you added to a Subscription. But how the API of the software stack provides you the change differs slightly.